# Error ! MNIST.npz is not UTF-8 encoded error saving disabled

Tags: utf-8, mnist

When I want to load the MNIST.npz dataset with this format **(mnist. npz)** in Jupyter; I use from below codes to load the file but this error appeared that showed my file does not exist **[FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'MNIST_data/mnist.npz']**.
When I checked it from my files and tried to open it, another error appeared that said mnist.npz is not UTF-8 encoded saving disabled.

How can I fix it? Help me pls.

My codes in Jupyter:

```
import numpy as np
path = "MNIST_data/mnist.npz"
with np.load(path, allow_pickle=True) as f:
   print(type(f))
   x_train, y_train = f\['x_train'\], f\['y_train'\]
   x_test, y_test = f\['x_test'\], f\['y_test'\]
```

Comment: You cannot open a binary file on an editor. So the error in the title. But it is expected. The real error is about not finding the file. Probably you have wrong expectation of the "current working directory" of your python code. Either use full paths, or check/set the directory python uses at start.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, Thank you so much for helping me, I found the solution to solve the problem. For opening that type of data we have to use " encoding="ASCII" ", I did that and my .npz file loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MNIST.npz dataset with npz format is not UTF-8 encoding and for that reason, I couldn't load it with the codes which I shared in my question box. But finally, I found the solution; If you want to solve the error you should use '**ASCII**' encoding like the below codes:

```
import numpy as np
path = "File address in your system"
with np.load(path, allow_pickle=True, encoding='ASCII' ) as f:
  print(type(f))
  x_train, y_train = f\['x_train'\], f\['y_train'\]
  x_test, y_test = f\['x_test'\], f\['y_test'\]
```

***Good luck***